# Javascript behind the scene-Variable for Generator

Tags: javascript, iterator, data-visualization

I have a question about generator in Javascript.

I encountered an example as below.

```
var gennumcollect = gennum();

for (var nums of gennumcollect) {
    console.log(nums)
}

function *gennum() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
    yield i
  }
}
```

I tried to tweak this by changing the generator to a regular function.

like,

```
function gennum(){
for( let i=0; i<150; i++) {
return i}}
```

The reason why I tried to tweak this way is that I thought generator is not essential for the
algorithm (to my understanding, generator is vital when I want to do something in asynchronized way, like doing it one by one not everything at once)

The reason I assume it didn't work out is because of this part.
var gennumcollect = gennum();

> It seems like , if I set the variable and equates it to a generator, 
>   it stores all the returns after iterating through the generator. Am I
>   right??

Additionally, 
What's the reason behind this code using generator, not just a regular function and return 
the values and store it in an array or object?

Original code is as below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/article-event-bubbling-and-delegation-3-xp4iy?from-embed

Comment: I can't quite understand what you're asking...?

Comment: Please don't hide closing `}` at the end of the line like that, and please *do* use indentation. Both make your code easier to read.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hi, Thank you for the suggestions.
I wonder specifically "var gennumcollect = gennum();"
It seems like, gennumcollect variable is storing the yields of the generator.
Am I right? instead of defining the variable which is the generator, instead, it actually stores the values.

Comment: I've updated my answer to answer that. The key thing is that the logic of the generator function is suspended at `yield` waiting for the code using the generator to call `next` (implicitly via `for-of`, or explicitly). I've added a couple of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to tweak this by changing the generator to a regular function. like,
>
> ```
> function gennum(){
> for( let i=0; i<150; i++) {
> return i}}
> ```

That doesn't work because the first `return i` terminates the function. Calling the function will return the value `0`. Calling it again will still give you the value `0`.

> What's the reason behind this code using generator, not just a regular function and return the values and store it in an array or object?

In that specific example, you could return an array of all 150 values. So it's not the best example of a generator.

A couple of key things about generator functions and the generators they create:

- A generator is a useful way to create a sequence that never ends. Code using the generator uses a value at a time from it. In contrast, you can't put a sequence that never ends in an array.
- Generators are a very useful way to write iterators so that the code using them can use one value at a time. Consider how you loop through an array. You can loop through a generator's (iterator's) values in a similar way (or even the exact same way, via `for-of`).
- A generator function's code doesn't have to be a simple loop, although that's common. It can have arbitrarily complex logic in it, because you can do anything you want between `yield`s.
- A generator can *consume* values given to it by the code using it, rather than just *producing* values as the example in your question does. To receive values from the code using it, a generator function's code uses the result value of `yield`. That lest the code using the generator trigger logic within the generator function.

---

In a comment on the question you said:

> I wonder specifically "var gennumcollect = gennum();" It seems like, gennumcollect variable is storing the yields of the generator. Am I right? instead of defining the variable which is the generator, instead, it actually stores the values.

No, it stores the generator that the generator function returns. A generator is an object with a `next` method that gives you the "next" value from the generator that the function fines.

When you call a generator function, it creates and returns a generator object that will walk through the logic of the function. Nothing in the function has actually run yet at that point. It's only when code calls `next` to get the "next" value from the generator that the code in the generator function runs. Consider this example:

```js
function* gennum() {
    console.log("gennum: Starting");
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        console.log(`gennum: About to yield ${i}`);
        yield i;
        console.log(`gennum: Back from yield ${i}`);
    }
    console.log("gennum: Done");
}

console.log("main:   About to call `gennum`:");
const gen = gennum();
console.log("main:   Starting loop:");
for (const v of gen) {
    console.log(`main:   Got the value ${v}`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Notice how you don't see `gennum: Starting` until we've started the `for-of` loop in the main script.

You can also call `next` manually, which is what lets you put values into the generator:

```js
function* gennum() {
    console.log("gennum: Starting");
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        console.log(`gennum: About to yield ${i}`);
        const v = yield i;
        console.log(`gennum: Back from yield ${i}, got value ${v}`);
    }
    console.log("gennum: Done");
}

console.log("main:   About to call `gennum`:");
const gen = gennum();

console.log("main:   1st call to `next`:");
let result = gen.next();
console.log(`main:   Result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);

console.log("main:   2nd call to `next`, passing in A:");
result = gen.next("A");
console.log(`main:   Result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);

console.log("main:   3rd call to `next`, passing in B:");
result = gen.next("B");
console.log(`main:   Result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Crowder
Just to make sure, 
The "A" , "B" don't have any significance in the gen.next() right?
It's just a place holder to see things clearly.
The reason Why I ask is gen.next() is not supposed to receive any parameter. 
It would be grateful if you could reply but I already think I aksed too much. Appreciate it.

Comment: @BS100 - Why do you think `gen.next()` shouldn't receive a parameter? :-) That's the point of the example, to show that the code using the generator can send it values. If you look at the the output, you'll see that the generator function's code receives those values (the `v` in `const v = yield i;`) and uses them (in its output). This is one of the key things about generators that makes them not just iterators: iterators are one-way (they only provide values). Generators are two-way (they both provide *and* consume values).

Comment: @BS100 - FWIW, I go into generators (and iterators and such) in some depth in Chapter 6 of my new book coming out in a couple of months, see my profile if you're interested.

Comment: Oh! that's a great news for me Thank you so much! I Will

Answer (score 2):

While it is the case that generators are often associated with asynchronous processes, they are much more general than that. In general, a generator function returns an [`iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators), which you can think of as a generalization of an array. Essentially, an iterator is any object that has a way of producing a (possibly unending) sequence of values.

When you changed the function from a generator to a regular function, that changed its return value from an iterator to a plain old value. The problem then occurs here:

```
for (var nums of gennumcollect) { ...
```

If `gennumcollect` is a sequence of values, then this makes sense, but it doesn't if it is simply a number.

If you're curious, try this out: replace your `gennum` function with this:

```
function gennum() {
  return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
}
```

Your example should work again.

To sum up: the root of the problem is that the loop:

```
for (var nums of gennumcollect) { ...
```

expects `gennumcollect` to be an [`iterable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols). However, when you changed your function from a generator function to a regular function, it no longer returns an `iterable`, but a regular value. In order to resolve this issue, `gennum` needs to return some kind of `iterable` (an example of which is an `Array`).

Comment: Really appreciate it, i have one more question, can I ask?
I wonder specifically "var gennumcollect = gennum();" It seems like, gennumcollect variable is storing the yields of the generator. Am I right?
 instead of defining the variable which is the generator, instead, it actually stores the values.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally edited *your* answer rather than *mine*. :-) Fixed it.

Comment: *"In general, a generator function returns an iterator..."* Nit: It returns a generator, not just an iterator. While generators are also iterators, they're more than just iterators.

Comment: Good catch, T.J.!